# ¿Cómo restar horas usando moment JS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy tratando de hacer restas entre dos horas usando *moment*.

Probé este método para restar hf - hi, lo que debería retornar como resultado: 00:53:00

```
let hi = '2022-12-24 09:00:00'
let hf = '2022-12-24 09:53:00' 


let tiempoAtencion = moment(hf).subtract(hi, 'HH').format('HH:mm:ss');
// PERO devuelve 09:53:00
```

Probé este segundo método:

```
let resta = moment(hf) - moment(hi);
//PERO devuelve 18:53:00
```

**Cabe mencionar que para que *moment* reconozca el formato debe estar la fecha en las variables**

Comment: Primero formatea el hi y así solo tener las horas. De la forma en como la haces estás formateando el resultado y no el hi.

Comment: con diff -> `moment(hf).diff(moment(hi), 'hours');` más info [aquí](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/)

Comment: dejando las variables en solo hora:    let hi = '09:00:00';
    let hf = '09:53:00';    y aplicando lo que mencionas obtengo NaN

Comment: ¿Te sirve hacerlo sin MomentJS? Ten en cuenta que es una librería [abandonada y sin soporte en la actualidad](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). Pero en todo caso, no es nada que no puedas hacer con el objeto Date directamente. Saludos

Comment: Cualquier ayuda me sería útil, mejor si es nativo.

Answer (score 2):

El método [a.diff(b, [unidad de tiempo])](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/) (diferencia) se puede usar con dos instancias de moment.js

`a` y `b` son las dos instancias de moment.
"unidad de tiempo" es de typo `string`: "seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days", "months", "years".

```js
let hi = '2022-12-24 09:00:00'
let hf = '2022-12-24 09:53:00' 

// Crear instancias de moment
const momentHi = moment(hi)
const momentHf = moment(hf)

let diferenciaEnMinutos = momentHf.diff(momentHi, "minutes")
console.log(diferenciaEnMinutos) // 53

//para obtener un resultado bien formateado:
let tiempoAtencion = moment()
  .set("Hours", 0)
  .set("Minutes", diferenciaEnMinutos)
  .set("Seconds", 0)
  .format("HH:mm:ss")

console.log(tiempoAtencion) // 00:53:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tú quieres es una diferencia de tiempo, es decir un `Timespan`, entiendo que no existe nativamente este tipo de objeto en javascript, pero creo que se puede crear uno.

**1.- Lo primero es entender que te arroja la diferencia de Date.**

Cuando restas 2 `Date` te da la diferencia de tiempo en milisengudos

```js
let hi = new Date('2022-12-24 09:00:00');
let hf = new Date('2022-12-24 09:53:00');

let dif = hf-hi;
console.log(dif); //3180000 milisegundos
```

**2.- Creación de la clase**

Creamos una clase `TimeSpan` para poner toda la lógica necesaria en él

```js
class TimeSpan{
  constructor(milisegundos){
    this.Value=milisegundos;
    for (const def of TimeSpan.definiciones) {
      this[def.key] = this.Value  / def.factor;
    }
  }
static definiciones = [
      {key: 'TotalYears', factor: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 1000, nombre: "Años" },
      {key: 'TotalDays', factor: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, nombre: "Días" },
      {key: 'TotalHours', factor: 60 * 60 * 1000, nombre: "Horas" },
      {key: 'TotalMinutes', factor: 60 * 1000, nombre: "Minutos" },
      {key: 'TotalSeconds', factor: 1 * 1000, nombre: "Segundos" }
    ]; 
}

let hi = new Date('2022-12-21 02:00:01');
let hf = new Date('2022-12-24 09:53:00');

let ts = new TimeSpan(hf-hi);

console.log(ts);
```

Tenemos una estructura de definición (`definiciones`) para las partes que componen el Timespan (años, dias, etc), incluyendo un factor de conversión desde milisegundo a la unidad en cuestión y un nombre que servirá para imprimir en pantalla.

Luego en el constructor anexamos cada definición y con esto obtenemos un Objeto que contiene el total de días, horas, etc a partir de unos milisegundos dados. Cabe señalar que cada total es independiente e equivalente entre sí.

Por ejemplo `4792.98333333333` minutos es equivalente a `287579` segundos

**3.- Conversión a string**

Seguramente necesitamos una función que nos retorne el total en conjunto algo como `34 minutos 4 segundos`

Para esto creamos una función toString

```
toString()
  {
     let res = [];
     let value = this.Value;
     for (const def of TimeSpan.definiciones) {
        if(this[def.key] <1 || value==0)  continue;
        let intPart =  Math.floor(value / def.factor); //nos quedamos con la parte entera
        
         //De los milisegundos originales sacados la unidad correspondiente 
//que ya usamos, por ejemplo si tenemos 10.4 minutos (618000ms) ya habríamos 
//ocupado la parte entera, es decir 10min (600000ms), entonces para el próximos 
//calculo (los segundos) tendremos que ocupar 18000ms restantes
        value = value - (intPart * def.factor);

//---------------------------------------------------------

        let nombre = intPart == 1 ? def.nombre.substring(0, def.nombre.length - 1) : def.nombre; // esto es para obtener el nombre en plurar o singular
        res.push(`${intPart} ${nombre}`);
         
      }
      
        return res.join(", ");
  }
```

La idea general de esta función es empezar con los milisegundos originales, recorrer los totales hasta encontrar un valor mayor o igual a 1, obtener su parte entera y dejar el resto de milisegundos para el próximo total.

**4.- El código completo más alguno pequeños añadidos**

```js
class TimeSpan{
  constructor(milisegundos){
    this.Value=milisegundos;
    for (const def of TimeSpan.definiciones) {
      this[def.key] = this.Value  / def.factor;
    }
  }
  
  toString()
  {
     let res = [];
     let value = this.Value;
     for (const def of TimeSpan.definiciones) {
        if(this[def.key] <1 || value==0)  continue;
        let intPart =  Math.floor(value / def.factor);
        
        value = value - (intPart * def.factor);
        let nombre = intPart == 1 ? def.nombre.substring(0, def.nombre.length - 1) : def.nombre;
        res.push(`${intPart} ${nombre}`);
         
      }
      
        return res.join(", ");
  }
  valueOf(){
    return this.value;
  }
  static FromMiliseconds(ms){
    return new TimeSpan(ms);
  }
  static FromSeconds(s){
    return new TimeSpan(s * 1000);
  }
  
   static definiciones = [
      {key: 'TotalYears', factor: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 1000, nombre: "Años" },
      {key: 'TotalDays', factor: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, nombre: "Días" },
      {key: 'TotalHours', factor: 60 * 60 * 1000, nombre: "Horas" },
      {key: 'TotalMinutes', factor: 60 * 1000, nombre: "Minutos" },
      {key: 'TotalSeconds', factor: 1 * 1000, nombre: "Segundos" }
    ]; 

}


let hi = new Date('2022-12-24 09:00:00');
let hf = new Date('2022-12-24 09:53:00' );

let date = TimeSpan.FromMiliseconds(hf-hi);
console.log(date.toString());
```