¿Existe algo como el DateDiff de Visual Basic en JavaScript?
Me preguntaba si en JavaScript... ¿Existe alguna función que haga algo cómo el DateDiff del Visual Basic? Por lo que he visto, las fechas se pueden diferenciar entre ifs así que creo que tiene que haber una forma de llegar a lo mismo desde JavaScript y la desconozco.
La intención es poder saber cuanto tiempo hay de diferencia entre 2 fechas que han de dar años, meses, días, horas, minutos y segundos.
Agradezco todas las respuestas a este dilema.

No, no existe nativamente algo similar. Tendrías que usar una librería de terceros o algo como esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/575411/301324

@Yussef por qué no lo votamos como duplicado?

Esta pregunta es similar a: ¿Cómo restar horas usando moment JS?. Si crees que es diferente, por favor [edit] la pregunta, aclara en qué es diferente y/o cómo las respuestas en la otra pregunta no son útiles para tu problema.

@Mateo Porque el DateDiff de VB no es igual que esa respuesta, cosa que acabo de comprobar

Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración... Esta pregunta no busca ayuda con la depuración, por lo que el motivo de cierre no aplica. Tampoco es necesario un código para responderla, por lo que no necesitaría más detalle. Y tampoco aplica "la norma de facto" de solicitar "esfuerzo" ya que la pregunta ha sido autorrespondida. Entonces no existe motivo alguno para su cierre

Acabo de completar la parte que no sabia y es que entre restas, divisiones y multiplicaciones he logrado resolver-lo así:


function AnosDiff(Fecha1, Fecha2){
    var Diferencia = Fecha1 - Fecha2;
    var Anual = ((((((Diferencia / 365) / 12)/ 31)/ 24)/ 60)/ 60)/ 1000;
    return parseInt(Anual * 365);
}
function MesesDiff(Fecha1, Fecha2){
    var Diferencia = Fecha1 - Fecha2;
    var Anual = ((((((Diferencia / 365) / 12)/ 31)/ 24)/ 60)/ 60)/ 1000;
    return parseInt(Anual * 365 * 12);
}
function DiasDiff(Fecha1, Fecha2){
    var Diferencia = Fecha1 - Fecha2;
    var Anual = ((((((Diferencia / 365) / 12)/ 31)/ 24)/ 60)/ 60)/ 1000;
    return parseInt(Anual * 365 * 12 * 31);
}
function HorasDiff(Fecha1, Fecha2){
    var Diferencia = Fecha1 - Fecha2;
    var Anual = ((((((Diferencia / 365) / 12)/ 31)/ 24)/ 60)/ 60)/ 1000;
    return parseInt(Anual * 365 * 12 * 31 * 24);
}
function MinutosDiff(Fecha1, Fecha2){
    var Diferencia = Fecha1 - Fecha2;
    var Anual = ((((((Diferencia / 365) / 12)/ 31)/ 24)/ 60)/ 60)/ 1000;
    return parseInt(Anual * 365 * 12 * 31 * 24 * 60);
}
function SegundosDiff(Fecha1, Fecha2){
    var Diferencia = Fecha1 - Fecha2;
    var Anual = ((((((Diferencia / 365) / 12)/ 31)/ 24)/ 60)/ 60)/ 1000;
    return parseInt(Anual * 365 * 12 * 31 * 24 * 60 * 60);
}



Así creo que esta todo cómo en visual basic pero con las diferencias entre lenguajes

Sin contar la forma nominal del año, yo uso la que considero verdadera, que es la que prevalece para ejercer acciones con los datos. La diferencia técnica tiene que ser precisa en su resolución.

Cuántos paréntesis. Notas un patrón en el código? No crees que es mejor definir una función respecto a las demás? Por ejemplo: function MesesDiff(a, b) { return AnosDiff(a, b) * 12; }.

¿Cuantos años hay entre el 31-12-1999 y el 01-01-2000?
La respuesta es depende:

Si consideras que un año son 365 y pico días, ha pasado 0 años
Si consideras el cambio de nominal del año, ha pasado 1 año

Existe una dificultad al contar el paso del tiempo, años y meses no tienen un equivalente en días fijos. Hay años con 365 días y otros con 366. Hay meses con 28,29,30 y 31 días
¿Cómo lo hace Visual Basic con DateDiff?

Años, Meses y Semestres: Usa el valor nominal
Para otros valores, se calcula a partir de los días transcurridos

Entonces dado el siguiente programa en VB:

El equivalente en Javascript es:


function DateDiff(interval, date1, date2) {
    const diffYear = (d1,d2) => d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()

    switch(interval){
      case DateInterval.Year:
        return diffYear(date1,date2);
      case DateInterval.Month:
        return diffYear(date1,date2) * 12 + date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth();
      case DateInterval.Day:
      case DateInterval.Hour:
      case DateInterval.Minute:
      case DateInterval.Second:
      case DateInterval.Hour:
        return Math.floor((date2 - date1) / interval);
      case DateInterval.Weekday:
        return Math.floor(((date2 - date1) / DateInterval.Day) / 7 );
      case DateInterval.Quarter:
         return diffYear(date1,date2) * 4 +  Math.floor(date2.getMonth() / 3) -  Math.floor(date1.getMonth() / 3);
      default:
         return "Error";
    }
}
const DateInterval = {
  Year: 1,
  Month: 2,
  Weekday:3,
  Quarter:4,
  Day: 86400000,
  Hour: 360000,
  Minute: 60000,
  Second: 1000
};



let hi = new Date('2022-10-21 00:00:00');
let hf = new Date('2023-12-24 00:00:00');


console.log("Años",     DateDiff(DateInterval.Year,    hi,hf)    );
console.log("Meses",    DateDiff(DateInterval.Month,   hi,hf)    );
console.log("Días",     DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,     hi,hf)    );
console.log("Minutos",  DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,  hi,hf)    );
console.log("Semanas",  DateDiff(DateInterval.Weekday, hi,hf)    );
console.log("Semestres",DateDiff(DateInterval.Quarter, hi,hf)    );




Aceptando la distancia entre fecha1 y fecha2 los años que han pasado son 0.

@PolFlórezViciana No entendí el comentario

Gracias por tu información. Ya he resuelto el posible problema, ahora estoy en otros.

@PolFlórezViciana Nada que agradecer, aunque igual quedé con la duda de que me estabas señalando con Aceptando la distancia entre fecha1 y fecha2 los años que han pasado son 0
